Tkinter Entry Box Focus Issue in Raspberry Pi 4
When running a Python program with multiple entry boxes on a Raspberry Pi 4, the entry boxes do not show the cursor or accept keyboard input. Instead, all keyboard input is sent to the console from which the program was launched.
I have two files, main.py and GUI.py.
From main.py, I run GUI.py.
main.py file:
from GUI import *

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    gui = CANGui("v.1.11.0")
    gui.build()
    #gui.root.overrideredirect(True)
    gui.root.mainloop() 

In GUI.py file the code is long, but summarizing the important parts, the code is as follows:
class CANGui():
    def __init__(self, gui_revision: str):  
        self.gui_revision = gui_revision
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
        self.root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), self.root.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.root.title(f"CanInterfaceGUI {self.gui_revision}")
        
        # --- Menu Options
        # ... Menu bar Options ...
    
        # --- Variable Initialization
        #...
        self.id_text = StringVar()
        self.payload_entry = StringVar()
        self.payload_entry.set("")
        self.can_sender_var = StringVar()
       
        self.screen_width_h = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() // 23
        self.screen_height_h = self.root.winfo_screenheight() // 65
        self.screen_width_v = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() // 25
        self.screen_height_v = self.root.winfo_screenheight() // 100
        #...

        # --- Threads
        # ...  (Not interfering or using any of the entry boxes)

    def build(self):
        self.can_frame1 = Frame(self.root, highlightbackground='grey', highlightthickness=3)
        self.can_frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.can_frame2 = Frame(self.root, highlightbackground='grey', highlightthickness=3)
        self.can_frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)  
        
        # frame 1
        # ... frame1 widgets ...

        # frame 2
        #...
        self.frame_id_Label = Label(self.can_frame2, text="ID (0x)")
        self.frame_id_Label.grid(row = 0, column=4, padx=(5,0), sticky='w')
        self.default_label_color = self.frame_id_Label.cget('fg')

        self.frame_id_entry = Entry(self.can_frame2, textvariable=self.id_text, width= 10)
        self.frame_id_entry.grid(row = 1, column=4, padx=(5,0))
        self.default_entry_color = self.frame_id_entry.cget('fg')

        self.payload_Label = Label(self.can_frame2, text="PAYLOAD")
        self.payload_Label.grid(row = 0, column=5, sticky='w')

        self.payload_Entry = Entry(self.can_frame2, textvariable=self.payload_entry)
        self.payload_Entry.grid(row = 1, column=5)

        self.root.update()

    # .. the rest of the code

I tried to focus on the first entry box, but what's strange is that none of the entry boxes are active. Everything was working fine until a couple of days ago, and the only recent change I made was not related to this issue.
Also, an interesting thing is that if I interact with the GUI (by pressing a button or triggering some event), the entry boxes show the cursor but not the text.
I know this is not a lot of information, but if you have any ideas, please let me know.
If you need more details about a certain portion of the code for better understanding, please refer to it.
Thanks for the help.

Problem resolved after removing in GUI.py line:
self.root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
Apparently, this command creates some focus issue with the other widgets.
